# UICollectionView highlighted cell with shadow

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView in which the centre cell will be highlighted as shown below image.

[image]

i have used following code to make shadow around the center cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : STSuggestStyleCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row == 4{

        cell.imageProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        cell.imageProfile.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.imageProfile.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0);
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowOpacity = 2.0;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.masksToBounds = false;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.imageProfile.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.imageProfile.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

                    cell.imageProfile.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    }

    return cell
}
```

But it is not working properly.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the above design using UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the red line for the cell in the center

[image]

The cell itself does not have shadow effects. The shadow is on the neighbor cells. So what you need to do here is to ask the cell to "overlay" on other cells.

Simply call `cell.clipToBounds = true` to allow your center cell to overlay on neighbor cells. Then make sure you expend your shadow effect out of the center cell.

Comment: @Aman.Sanghani Are you able to see the shadow? Or the shadow in inside the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create two different cell. because of its reuse feature.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 4{
        let cell : STSuggestStyleCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        cell.imageProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        cell.imageProfile.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.imageProfile.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0);
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowOpacity = 2.0;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.masksToBounds = false;
        cell.imageProfile.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.imageProfile.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.imageProfile.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

        cell.imageProfile.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell : STSuggestNomalCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```